# change color of current page angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Does AngularJS help in any way with setting an active class on the link for the current page?

I imagine there is some magical way in angularjs or css this is done, but I can't seem to find.

My menu looks like:

```html
<ul>
 <li ><a href="#/person" ng-click = "person()" id="bl" >Person</a></li>
<li><a href="#/product" ng-click = "product()" id="or"  >Product</a></li>
<li ><a href="#/place" ng-click = "place()" id="gr" >Place</a></li>
</ul><br/><br/>
```

my css looks like:

```css
body {
font-family: Source Sans Pro;
}

ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}


a{
    float: left;
    width: 6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
 
}

#navbar li a.current {
background-color: #FFF;}

li {
    display: inline;
}

#bl {
background-color:#5a5a5a;
color: yellow;
}

#or {
background-color:#5a5a5a;
color: yellow;
}

#gr {
background-color : #5a5a5a;
color: yellow;
}

#bl:hover ,#or:hover , #gr:hover   {
 background-color:#ff6900;
 }
 
 #persons{
 float:left; 
 }
 
 .left{ 
 float:left;
 }
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: nope,i'm using angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have functions person(), product(). Set background-color by using `getElementsByName('body').style.backgroundColor = 'red';` and respective colors in respective functions.

Comment: It would be `getElementsByName('body').style.backgroundColor = 'red';` , I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route service to get/detect the current route and set some `class` in your `li` or `a` tag then use css to style them based on the class you set.